# Multiple commands produce ../Debug-iphonesimulator/RA_Swift copy.app/Info.plist': 1)

Tags: ios, swift

when I add facebookcore sdk in my project with cocoa pod I am getting this error

I have delete my derived data and restart Xcode already.i have also update pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
File< project setting or workspace setting 
and change Build system setting to legacy build system

[image]